Higcharts annotations for Wordcloud and Dependency wheel
I'm trying to add annotations for Highcharts charts, and I'm having trouble with Wordcloud and Dependency wheel. API docs states that annotations could be specified via the point ID, so I tried to do that, but Wordcloud display the annotation in the top left corner, and Dependency wheel just does not display anything.
Do you have any idea on how to resolve this?
I created a JSfiddle based on the Higcharts demo for those
Wordcloud: https://jsfiddle.net/eqLrz70o/1/
const text =
        'Chapter 1. Down the Rabbit-Hole ' +
        'Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on ' +
        'the bank, and of having nothing to do: ' +
        'once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, ' +
        'but it had no pictures or conversations ' +
        'in it, \'and what is the use of a book,\' thought Alice ' +
        '\'without pictures or conversation?\'' +
        'So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for ' +
        'the hot day made her feel very sleepy ' +
        'and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be ' +
        'worth the trouble of getting up and picking ' +
        'the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close ' +
        'by her.',
    lines = text.replace(/[():'?0-9]+/g, '').split(/[,\. ]+/g),
    data = lines.reduce((arr, word) => {
        let obj = Highcharts.find(arr, obj => obj.name === word);
        if (obj) {
            obj.weight += 1;
        } else {
            obj = {
                    id: word,
                name: word,
                weight: 1
            };
            arr.push(obj);
        }
        return arr;
    }, []);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    accessibility: {
        screenReaderSection: {
            beforeChartFormat: '<h5>{chartTitle}</h5>' +
                '<div>{chartSubtitle}</div>' +
                '<div>{chartLongdesc}</div>' +
                '<div>{viewTableButton}</div>'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data,
        name: 'Occurrences'
    }],
    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
        point: 'the',
        text: 'POINT BY ID'
      },
      {
        point: {x:100, y:100},
        text: 'POINT BY PX'
      }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Wordcloud of Alice\'s Adventures in Wonderland',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'An excerpt from chapter 1: Down the Rabbit-Hole',
        align: 'left'
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 16px"><b>{point.key}</b>' +
            '</span><br>'
    }
});

Dependency wheel: https://jsfiddle.net/h0zd4jwk/
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Dependency Wheel'
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. From {point.from} to ' +
                '{point.to}: {point.weight}.'
        }
    },
    
    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
        point: {x: 200, y: 200},
        text: 'Point by PX'
      },{
        point: 'brazil-france',
        text: 'Point by ID'
      }]
    }],

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'id'],
        data: [
            ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5],
            ['Brazil', 'France', 1, 'brazil-france'],
            ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
            ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Canada', 'France', 5],
            ['Canada', 'England', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'France', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5],
            ['Mexico', 'England', 1],
            ['USA', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['USA', 'France', 1],
            ['USA', 'Spain', 1],
            ['USA', 'England', 5],
            ['Portugal', 'Angola', 2],
            ['Portugal', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'Morocco', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'South Africa', 3],
            ['France', 'Angola', 1],
            ['France', 'Senegal', 3],
            ['France', 'Mali', 3],
            ['France', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['France', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['Spain', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['England', 'Angola', 1],
            ['England', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['England', 'Morocco', 2],
            ['England', 'South Africa', 7],
            ['South Africa', 'China', 5],
            ['South Africa', 'India', 1],
            ['South Africa', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Angola', 'China', 5],
            ['Angola', 'India', 1],
            ['Angola', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Senegal', 'China', 5],
            ['Senegal', 'India', 1],
            ['Senegal', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Mali', 'China', 5],
            ['Mali', 'India', 1],
            ['Mali', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Morocco', 'China', 5],
            ['Morocco', 'India', 1],
            ['Morocco', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Japan', 'Brazil', 1]
        ],
        type: 'dependencywheel',
        name: 'Dependency wheel series',
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#333',
            style: {
                textOutline: 'none'
            },
            textPath: {
                enabled: true
            },
            distance: 10
        },
        size: '95%'
    }]

});


Hi @Sleeper9, Unfortunately, annotations are not currently supported in Wordcloud and Dependency-wheel series. This is due to how these series are generated and, consequently, the lack of access to the point coordinates. Here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/21675 is a reported feature request.

Turned out this feature is missing. There's a github issue to track progress https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/21675
